# Application of theorem of Brauer on finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

In theory of finite simple groups, the following is a well celebrated

> **Theorem (Brauer-Fowler)** If $G$ is a finite simple group and $z$ is an element of order $2$ such that centralizer of $z$ has order $n$ in $G$ then $G$ can be embedded in the alternating group $A_{n^2-1}$.

**Question 1.** Do any one lists an  example(s) of simple group(s) in which $G$ can not be embedded in $A_{n^2-2}$?

---

**Ignore next statements and question 2**

Considering families of simple groups other than $A_n$, some simple groups in other families are isomorphic with some alternating groups (for example $\rm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)\cong A_5$).

**Question 2.** Is there any example of a simple group $G$ in the family of sporadic groups or classical groups to which, by applying theorem of Brauer-Fowler, we get the embedding to be an *isomorphism*?

---

Both questions are almost similar, but I had put them in different form, concerning some special interests in the theorem stated.

Comment: With your note, the question 2 has no good meaning. I will put [ignore] on it.

Comment: @Derek: wait; $GL_4(2)$ is $A_8$, isn't it? And now question 2. In $GL_4(2)$, is there any involution whose centralizer has order $3$? (Then I can apply theorem of Brauer to get injection from $GL_4(2)$ to $A_8$, and because of same orders, the embedding is isomorphism.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm going senile! Let's start again.  The examples of alternating groups isomorphic to finite simple groups in other families are $A_5 \cong {\rm  PSL}(2,4) \cong {\rm PSL}(2,5)$, $A_6 \cong {\rm PSL}(2,9)$, and $A_8 \cong {\rm PSL}(4,2)$.

Comment: No involution could possibly have a centralizer of order $3$. There are two conjugacy classes of involutions in ${\rm GL}_4(2)$, and their centralizers have orders $192$ and $96$.